# Updating DropDownList using minimalect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ok so the scenario is currently I am populating a drop down list from my model with the following code

```
ViewBag.LeaseCompanyID = new SelectList(ContractModelEntity.system_supplier.Where(x => x.Type == "Lease"), "CompanyID", "Name", data.LeaseCompanyID);
```

This works perfectly, however on my form I have a button located next to the drop down list which adds another option in the database, using ajax and a modal popup.

The controller code for this is here

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddSupplier([Bind(Include="Name,Type")] system_supplier data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ContractModelEntity.system_supplier.Add(data);
            ContractModelEntity.SaveChanges();
            return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When the new option is added into the database I then need to refresh my dropdownlist to get this new data (currently if I refresh the page I can see the new option).  I am using minimalect plugin for the drop downs.

Does anybody know a way of updating this minimalect list, there must be a way of building the list through an ajax call which returns some JSON data.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after doing a bit of research here is my solution, hopefully it will help other poeple.  Someone might even have a cleaner solution.

I first created a jsonresult controller method which looked like this

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult RetreiveSuppliers(string contractType)
    {
        var supplierData = ContractModelEntity.system_supplier.Where(x => x.Type == contractType);
        var result = new List<object>();
        foreach (var x in supplierData)
        {
            result.Add(new { Id = x.CompanyID, Name = x.Name });
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

That got me the data from the database.  then I created a javascript on the page which looks like this

```
$("body").on("click", "#btn_InsertNewSupplier", function () {
        var supForm = $("#addSupData");
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("AddLeaseSupplier", "Contract")",
            data: supForm.serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result === 0) {
                    var inst = $.remodal.lookup[$('[data-remodal-id=modal_AddSupplier]').data('remodal')];
                    inst.close();
                    NotificationAlert("success", "New Supplier Created");
                    GetNewSupplierList();
                } else {
                    NotificationAlert("error", "Failed Adding New Supplier");
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function GetNewSupplierList() {
        var actionurl = "@Url.Action("RetreiveSuppliers", "Contract", new { contractType = "Lease"})";
        $.getJSON(actionurl, tempdata);
    }

    function tempdata(response) {
        if (response != null) {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + response[i].Id + '">' + response[i].Name + '</option>';
            }
            $("#LeaseCompanyID").html(html);
        }
    }
```

So once the ajax call is successful it will trigger the GetNewSupplierList function which calls my controller method and returns some JSON data.  Once that is returned it calls tempdata, which builds the new HTML for my select picker, once that is built it updates the html on the selectpicker id.

Works like a charm!!!

Thanks to everyone who took a look at this post.